# gcc deleted by new aptitude package installation?

Tags: gcc, apt-get

i was running my makefile which was using gcc perfectly fine until it stopped after a second configuration to tell me zlib is missing. so i installed the lib64z1-dev package from aptitude and proceeded to run make again when it stopped by telling me it can't find gcc. i looked for gcc in /usr/bin and mysteriously it is gone. I have no record in my console of doing anything in between other than running apt-get to install the libz package. though it sounds strange, it seems like installing the package somehow deleted my gcc executable. does anyone know why happened?

Comment: if installing a dev package for a "simple" library forces removal of a compiler, then there's something seriously wrong with your setup, or the distro's packaging policies.

Comment: yes, i have recently installed PearOS, so it's just like a fresh install of Ubuntu...

Comment: this is probably too strange and doesn't give enough clues for somebody to help me with. it's no problem to reinstall the libc package for gcc but i just want to understand what phantom caused this

Comment: check the dependencies of whatever you installed. it'll say what it requires, what it supersedes, etc...

Comment: apt-cache depends lib64z1-dev
lib64z1-dev:i386
  Depends: lib64z1:i386
  Depends: zlib1g-dev:i386
  Depends: <lib64c-dev:i386>
    libc6-dev-amd64:i386
  Replaces: <amd64-libs-dev>
  Replaces: <amd64-libs-dev:i386>

Comment: http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/amd64-libs   i think this is telling me that lib64gcc1 depends on amd64-libs-dev (or is it the other way around?). in any case this gives me more of an explanation

Comment: okay at this point i can't even do sudo apt-get autoremove because sudo and su have been removed from the /usr/bin. i think i'll have to take this up with the PearOS people. but isn't the apt package management independent of the distribution as long as its debian? is there a difference in how one debian distro handles apt packaging from another?

Comment: in that case, your system is totally hosed. Installing a library should **NOT** cascade up the system tree and remove fundamental system binaries. If sudo and su are gone, your system is totally fubared.

Comment: yes i'll be reinstalling my os. my question is, is this a problem with the particular distribution? because aren't all dependencies and package managing done by debian?

Comment: no. debian might have been the basis of pearos, but the pearos people will simply take debian packages, compile them themselves, and add/remove/customize whatever it is they do to make "pearos" different from plain debian. Consider it like a Samsung Android phone. It might be running Google's Android, but Samsung's done a LOT to customize/modify the thing, so it's no longer "plain" android - problems with a samsung phone are samsung's problems, not googles, because it's not the original OS anymore.

Comment: okay thanks for explaining that point. i'll comment on pearOS's forum, i guess that should help them.

Comment: and i guess this is why it's better to use the more popular distros like ubuntu and mint...